# Can the area of a finite integral be negative?

Tags: integration, area

How is it possible to obtain a negative area when you integrate a function between 2 limits? Does this imply that the curve is below the x-axis? Is that how it is interpreted and should you give your answer as the modulus of the integral?

Comment: There's no such thing as "the area of an integral." One may use an integral to find an area of a set of points in the plane, or to find the volume of a set of points in three-dimensional space, or to find the length of a curve, or to find the velocity of a particle that has moved in a conservative force field, or to find a probability, or to find any of a number of other things. But the area of a set of points in the plane is the area _OF_ that set of points, not _OF_ an integral.

Comment: so what should i have said? the area under a finite integral?

Comment: You might have said "Can the area bounded by a curve be negative?" $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Negative area means, intuitively, that there is "more area" on the $-y$ half-plane than on the $+y$ half-plane, at least within the range of $x$ in which the integral was evaluated. As an example, take the functions $f(x) = 1$ and $g(x) = -1$ and integrate them, say, from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$. Another useful example is $f(x) = x$. Try to integrate it using different ranges for $x$, say, from $x=-1$ to $x=0$, then $x=0$ to $x=1$, $x=-1$ to $x=1$ and so on. These examples might be helpful to ilustrate the point since the area under the curve can be also calculated using the formula for the area of a triangle.

Comment: but in your answer, should you give the modulus of that negative area or can you leave it as a negative answer?

Comment: You should leave it as a negative answer.

Comment: but if you leave your answer as negative for the area of the function f(x)=x, from x=-1 to x=0 , the areas will cancel each other out because of the negative sign and you will end up with the area equaling zero right? but the area cannot be equal to zero?

Comment: if you do it another way, doing the integral from x=-1 to x=0 and adding the integral from x=0 to x=1 you would get one negative answer and one positive answer. if you add them you will end up with zero. that's what happens if you keep the - sign.

Comment: sorry, i meant from x=-1 to x=1

Comment: @butterfly you don't need to worry so much about the negative sign. It is supposed to indicate if the area under the curve is "more concentraded" in the $-y$ or in the $+y$ axis. The exercise I proposed to you is just a way to understand how the sign changes when you integrate different functions or the same function over a different range, so you can get a geometrical intuition of what's happening.

Comment: so i should leave my answer as 0 ?

Comment: @butterfly yes! Note that this always happens when one integrates an odd function over a symmetric range with respect to the origin.

Comment: an ''odd'' function?

Comment: @butterfly yes! A function is odd if $f(-x) = -f(x)$.

Comment: Does the name ''odd'' or ''even'' have to do anything with the highest power degree of the function in terms of x?

Comment: @butterfly this is a nice way to remember the name. But other functions (not necessarily monomials) have this property, e.g. $\cos(x)$ is even and $\sin(x)$ is odd.

Comment: But is this the relationship for non-monomial functions that aren't trigonometric terms ?

Comment: as well as for monomial functions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124627/discussion-between-butterfly-and-iamwill).

Comment: you seem to know more about math than me. could you please answer my other question on significant figures? it's not getting any answers.